# rails does not auto create package.json file and node_modules folder when I create the project folder?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails

Here is my problem.

I created my project by this command

```
rails new freelancer --database=postgresql
```

Everything ran seems ok.

But when I compare my code with the tutorial code, my code does not has these: `node_modules` folder and `package.json` file ?

I thought that maybe because I did not ran the `nodejs` code to install it? Or I did not install `nodejs`? But when I checked `nodejs` by this code `node -v` it showed me that `nodejs` had been installed to my mac ?

So how can I had those file and folder to my project? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Rails 3 [is a very old and unmantained version](https://endoflife.date/rails), so it doesn't come with any built-in node support. If you're starting a new project, there's no reason to use such an old rails version, just use the last one.

Comment: @AlterLagos: thanks for your comment. I have been update to Rails 7.0.4 and it still has the same problem ? Could you give me some advices ?

Comment: `package.json` file can be generated by running `npm init`